# MKAnnotation doesn't appear

Tags: ios, swift, location, mapkit

I'm writing flight ticket's app and have some troubles with map annotation's
So we have view, that showing all ticket information, and map with departure city and destination

Here's view loading :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.delegate = self
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    configureView(showingReturnData: showingReturnData, fromTicket: showingTicketNow)
    designSetup()

    mapSetting()
}
```

Converting to coordinates :

```
func gettingCoordinates(cityString: String) -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

    var returningCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D()

    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(cityString) { (placemarksArray, error) in
        if error == nil && placemarksArray?.count != 0 {
            let placemark = placemarksArray![0]

            print(placemark.country, placemark.name, 
             placemark.location!.coordinate.longitude, 
            placemark.location!.coordinate.latitude)

            //Here output:
            Optional("Japan") Optional("Tokyo") 139.6917 35.689506
            Optional("Russia") Optional("Moscow") 37.60946 55.7615902

            returningCoordinate.longitude = placemark.location!.coordinate.longitude
            returningCoordinate.latitude = placemark.location!.coordinate.latitude
        } else {
            print(error!)
        }
    }

    return returningCoordinate
}
```

And then adding annotations to map, but It's always the same place, near Africa in ocean

```
func mapSetting() {

    let fromPlacemark = gettingCoordinates(cityString: showingTicketNow.fromCityName)
    let toPlacemark = gettingCoordinates(cityString: showingTicketNow.toCityName)

    let fromAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    fromAnnotation.title = fromCityName.text!
    fromAnnotation.coordinate = fromPlacemark
    mapView.addAnnotation(fromAnnotation)

    let toAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    toAnnotation.title = toCityName.text!
    toAnnotation.coordinate = toPlacemark
    mapView.addAnnotation(toAnnotation)

    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: toPlacemark, latitudinalMeters: 
    10000, longitudinalMeters: 10000)
    mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
}
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing the asynchrone part of `geocodeAddressString()`. Just before the line `print(placemark.country`, do `print("Placemark")`. Just before `return returningCoordinate`, do "print("Will return")`. In what order do the prints appear in your console? You'll see.

Comment: @Larme How can I fix it?